# Apache2 and HeartBleed SSL issue

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, heartbleed-bug

I am using apache2 server runing on a Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.
In my apache2 conf file there is a host that looks like this.

IfModule mod_ssl.c>

VirtualHost *:443>

```
 //Every configuration for the virtual host working fine.
```

/VirtualHost>

/IfModule>

I avoid using the "minor" sign since SO does not display the line containing it.

I cannot read "OpenSSL" anywhere. So my intuition says that I am not using it at all. So I should not worry about Heart bleed open SSL bug.

Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command prompt do:
`openssl version`

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f (inclusive) are vulnerable
OpenSSL 1.0.1g is NOT vulnerable
OpenSSL 1.0.0 branch is NOT vulnerable
OpenSSL 0.9.8 branch is NOT vulnerable
```

Your config is using mod_ssl. [Mod SSL](http://www.modssl.org/) is OpenSSL built for Apache.

If your server is public facing you can try something like this tool. http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your fast response. The result was "OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012". Guess it is vulnerable. Would you let me know how to fix it?.

Comment: That has been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl